# string is not convertible to void

Tags: swift, function, type-conversion

I can't understand what is wrong with this function:

```
var arrayStatusUserTable:[String] = [String]()
var statusText:String = String()

func retrieveStatusInTable(name: String) -> String {

    var statusFinal:String = String()

    var query:PFQuery = PFQuery(className: "Status")
    query.whereKey("NameCreator", equalTo: name)
    query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock { (objects:[AnyObject]?, error:NSError?) -> Void in
        for phrase in objects! {
            let phraseTakenParse:String? = (phrase as! PFObject)["Status"] as? String

            if phraseTakenParse != nil {
                self.arrayStatusUserTable.append(phraseTakenParse!)
            }
        }
        // Take the last status
        if var frase = self.arrayStatusUserTable.last {
            var lastFraseStatus:String = frase //self.arrayStatusUtente.last!
            self.statusText = lastFraseStatus

            statusFinale = lastFraseStatus
            return statusFinale
        }
    }
}
```

This one return the error: 'String' is not convertible to 'Void'! I just wanna return the last object from the array filled from Parse! Thanks for helping me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`return statusFinale` written in blocks, so retrieveStatusInTable function return Void.

When you use asynchronous method, set function return type "Void" and tell result with blocks (completionHandler).

**Sample Code:**

```
func retrieveStatusInTable(name: String, completionHandler:((statusFinale: String) -> Void)) {

    // .....

    query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock { (objects:[AnyObject]?, error:NSError?) -> Void in
          // ........
          statusFinale = lastFraseStatus
          completionHandler(statusFinale: statusFinal)
    }
}
```

**Usage:**

```
retrieveStatusInTable("Sample", { (statusFinale) -> Void in
    println(statusFinale)
})
```

Comment: thank  you! the first part works fine! but the usage is giving me some problem: var subfrase:String = retrieveStatusInTable(arrayAmici[indexPath.row], completionHandler: { (statusFinale) -> Void in
            println(statusFinale)         the error is: () is not convertible to String!
        })

Comment: @LucaAlberto I see ur problem

Comment: @LucaAlberto your code `var subfrase:String =` is wrong;( `retrieveStatusInTable(..)` function return type changed to 'Void', your should remove `var subfrase:String =` code!

Comment: OK, you can use `statusFinale` in blocks. you write code about textLabel in completionHandler (in my sample, `println(statusFinale)`).

Comment: @LucaAlberto Excellent! Happy coding:)